# Sorting both ascending and descending based on keys in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
[
  {:string=>"2:aa/", :count=>2, :char=>"a"},
  {:string=>"2:dd/", :count=>2, :char=>"d"},
  {:string=>"2:ee/", :count=>2, :char=>"e"},
  {:string=>"=:gg/", :count=>2, :char=>"g"},
  {:string=>"1:ii/", :count=>2, :char=>"i"},
  {:string=>"=:nnn/", :count=>3, :char=>"n"},
  {:string=>"1:ooo/", :count=>3, :char=>"o"},
  {:string=>"2:sss/", :count=>3, :char=>"s"},
  {:string=>"1:uuu/", :count=>3, :char=>"u"}
]
```

I want this array of hashes to be sorted descending by count, and if count is equal, then I need to sort it ascending based on the char value.

Is there any direct way I can do this?

Comment: For an explanation of how Ruby orders arrays, see the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of negating the value via `-`, you could also use [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) with two arrays and switch the elements as needed.

To sort *ascending / ascending* you'd use: (see [`Array#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E))

```
ary.sort { |a, b| [a[:count], a[:char]] <=> [b[:count], b[:char]] }
```

to sort *descending / ascending*, you switch the first elements:

```
ary.sort { |a, b| [b[:count], a[:char]] <=> [a[:count], b[:char]] }
#                  ^                         ^
#                  |                         |
#                  +-------------------------+
```

to sort *ascending / descending*, you switch the second elements: (you get the idea)

```
ary.sort { |a, b| [a[:count], b[:char]] <=> [b[:count], a[:char]] }
#                             ^                         ^
#                             |                         |
#                             +-------------------------+
```

Comment: Note that this approach is just more general, not "more correct". Since your values _are_ numeric, [Ursus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605143/477037) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
a.sort_by { |item| [-item[:count], item[:char]] }
```

`a` is your array

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a direct way, so here's a way to remove even another indirection--your intermediate data structure. This assumes your hash is just a means to an end and you intend to sort the strings:

```
strings = ["2:aa/", "2:dd/", "2:ee/", "=:gg/", "1:ii/", "=:nnn/", "1:ooo/", "2:sss/", "1:uuu/"]

strings.sort_by{ |s| x = s[/\w+/]; [-x.size, x] }
```

The regex isolates the part you need to count and sort; it may need to be adjusted if your real data differs from the example.

(I would replace `x` with a more meaningful variable name based on what the letters represent)